# how to subtract 1 day from magneto 2 timezone function?

Tags: magento2.4.0, timezone, datetime

I have to use magento function for date and I wanna subtract 1 day from following code,how can I do it ? I do not want to use PHP function for date
how can I subtract 1 day from follwoing code ?

```
$fromDay = $this->timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento work with native `DateTime` objects and if you want to work with dates you need to create `DateTime` and use `DateInterval` for shifts

Example:

```php
$datetime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
$this->timezone->date($datetime)->format('Y-m-d');
```

P.S. You can check source of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone::date`